# Counting ints in an array?

Tags: ios, arrays

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Enter Food"])
    {
        Food *newFood = [[Food alloc]init];
        newFood.nameF =[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        newFood.caloriesF = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:1].text intValue];

        [FoodArray addObject:newFood];
```

I am creating a calorie counting app and obviously need to add up all of the calories entered for a total. So the calorie number goes into the array 'FoodArray' as caloriesF.

i had tried to use NSEnumerator but am not sure if that is the right thing to be using?

How do i add these up and display it in a TextField? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: The posted code seems to be used for a user to enter one food. Where's the code relevant to the question? Where's your attempt to add up all of the values and update the text field?

Comment: Yes i was trying to show what was going on before hand. I had attempted to use NSEnumerator from code i has seen on here but it doesn't look like the way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
int total = [[FoodArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.caloriesF"] intValue];
```

I'd also recommend following the naming conventions and not start variable names with a capital letter (CamelCase).

Answer (score 1):

Try iterating like this:

```
float calories = 0;
for (Food *foodObject in FoodArray){
    calories += [foodObject caloriesF];
}
NSLog(@"calories: %.2f",calories); //instead of printing just update your label
```

EDIT: Davids answer seems much easier^^

Comment: Absolutely no, David say the correct answer...before me :)

Comment: Yeah I know. Though I don't understand the downvote as my answer is not wrong. Just not that smart.

Comment: @MatteoGobbi Why do you say "absolutely no"? This is a perfectly fine answer. Personally I would never use David's answer over this one.

Comment: For 2 principal reasons: 1) ..valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.. is more performance than a for cycle; 2) 1 line VS 4 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. I rather like to iterate too but I find Davids way is kinda smooth as it's pretty short. Anyways, iterating makes it easier to find potential errors/wrong values.

Comment: @MatteoGobbi Why do you think `valueForKeyPath:` is faster? Purpose built code should always be faster than dynamically interpreted key-value coding.

Comment: I personally prefer this answer as i can see what is going on a lot better, but i can see why Davids answer is more efficient. He also reminded me about my naming conventions.. opps! Thank you for all your answers!

Comment: @rmaddy: maybe you are right on the performance, but i think that remains the best solution for elegance and code cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop to add up all of the calories:

```
NSInteger totalCal = 0;
for (FOOD *food in FoodArray) {
  totalCal += food.caloriesF
}
```

Or use KVC like in @David's answer:

```
NSInteger total = [[FoodArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.caloriesF"] integerValue];
```

Comment: Absolutely no, David say the correct answer...before me :)